# Update inside pagestorage from different page flutter

Tags: flutter

I use bottomNavigationBar in main page and I have 3 different page.
My screens

```
  final List<Widget> screens = [
    findLocation(),
    otherPage(),
    profilePage(),
  ];
```

and my wigdet build like this

```
    return Scaffold(
      body: PageStorage(
        child: currentScreen,
        bucket: bucket,
      ),
      floatingActionButton:  showFab?GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            currentScreen =
                findLocation(); // if user taps on this location tab will be active
            currentTab = 0;
          });
        },
```

Find location page like this

```
  ElevatedButton(
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        primary: Color(0xFF0B75E0), // background
                        onPrimary: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: [
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                right: 25.0, left: 15, top: 12, bottom: 10),
                            child: Text(
                              'Konum Bul',
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 1),
                                  fontSize: 23,
                                  letterSpacing: 1.5,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                  height: 1),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Icon(
                            Icons.arrow_forward,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.push(context,
                            new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new loginPage()));
                      },
                    ),
```

When I click a button on that page while my Find Location page is open, I want a different page to open than the 3 pages in main (I have a 4th login page) but my new loginpage open different place (without bottomnavigatorbar).

I want to open this page in main like the others. I want it to be tapbar underneath. How can I do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you ask about why bottomnavigatorbar not showing up in login page, the answer will be :

Because you do this code in onPressed:

```
Navigator.push(context,new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new loginPage()));
```

And this code will open a new rout.

**Try to write this code in onPressed :**

```
setState((){
   currentScreen = loginPage();
});
```

Comment: The problem is that my currentScreen variable is in the main page. I cannot change it from the location page. While browsing through the 3 existing pages on the Main page, I am already browsing by making currentScreen = 1, currentScreen = 2.

Comment: can you share full code of this page. I want to see data type for variables and other things